# unable to pass value to jinja2 template in python3

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

I am unable to `testcases` values from the jinja2 template.

python3 code:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader


testcases = [
    {'name' : 'testcase1', 'value' : 'PASS'},
    {'name': 'testcase2', 'value': 'FAIL'},
    {'name': 'testcase3', 'value': 'FAIL'},
]

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader("."))
template = env.get_template('./index.html')

content = template.render(testcases)
print(content)
```

Jinja3 html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <p1>Hello</p1>

    <div>
        <ul>
            {% for i in testcases %}
                <li>{{ i['name'] }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The value I am getting is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <p1>Hello</p1>

    <div>
        <ul>
            
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am expecting the value of testcase[i]['name'] but the field is empty.
Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: `template.render(testcases=testcases)` > https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#jinja2.Template.render

Answer (score 0):

`content = template.render(testcases = testcases)` should be used instead of `content = template.render(testcases)`